# Data is not being retrieve from Django Rest to Flutter App

Tags: django, flutter

I am trying to retrieve json data from django api restframework to flutter app but it shows nothing. Even retrieveRecord function in main.dart do not print text when app starts.

django returning json code on

http://localhost:8000/records/?format=api

it also shows json without format on http://localhost:8000/records/?format=json

but in flutter list views it shows nothing

Main.dart

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_application_1/ann.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test Phase Assignment',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Test Phase Assigment'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Client client = http.Client();
  List<AnnSystem> annSystem = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    _retrieveRecord();
    super.initState();
  }

  _retrieveRecord() async {
    annSystem = [];
    List response = json.decode((await client
            .get(Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/records/?format=json')))
        .body);
    response.forEach((element) {
      annSystem.add(AnnSystem.fromMap(element));
    });
    print(response); // it does not print on terminal
    print("function calling"); //it does not print on terminal
    setState(() {});
  }

  _addRecord() {}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          _retrieveRecord();
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: annSystem.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(annSystem[index].location),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _addRecord(),
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**annSystem.dart (class)**

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:convert';

class AnnSystem {
  int id;
  String tempratures;
  String location;
  String land_area;
  AnnSystem({
    required this.id,
    required this.tempratures,
    required this.location,
    required this.land_area,
  });

  AnnSystem copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? tempratures,
    String? location,
    String? land_area,
  }) {
    return AnnSystem(
      id: id ?? this.id,
      tempratures: tempratures ?? this.tempratures,
      location: location ?? this.location,
      land_area: land_area ?? this.land_area,
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'tempratures': tempratures,
      'location': location,
      'land_area': land_area,
    };
  }

  factory AnnSystem.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return AnnSystem(
      id: map['id'],
      tempratures: map['tempratures'],
      location: map['location'],
      land_area: map['land_area'],
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory AnnSystem.fromJson(String source) =>
      AnnSystem.fromMap(json.decode(source));

  @override
  String toString() {
    return 'AnnSystem(id: $id, tempratures: $tempratures, location: $location, land_area: $land_area)';
  }

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;
    
    return other is AnnSystem &&
        other.id == id &&
        other.tempratures == tempratures &&
        other.location == location &&
        other.land_area == land_area;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode {
    return id.hashCode ^
        tempratures.hashCode ^
        location.hashCode ^
        land_area.hashCode;
  }
}
```

**Django app Urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.resolvers import URLPattern
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.getRoutes),
    path('records/', views.getRecords),
    path('records/create/', views.createRecord),
    path('records/<str:pk>', views.getRecord),
    path('records/<str:pk>/update/', views.getRecord),
    path('records/<str:pk>/delete/', views.deleteRecord),
]
```

**Views.py**

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import RecordsSerializer
from .models import Records

@api_view(['GET','POST','DELETE'])
def getRoutes(request):
    routes = [
        {
            'Endpoint': '/recordss',
            'method': 'GET',
            'body': None,
            'desciption': 'return an array of all records'
        },
        {
            'Endpoint': '/recordss/id',
            'method': 'GET',
            'body': None,
            'desciption': 'return one single record'
        },
          {
            'Endpoint': '/recordss/create/',
            'method': 'POST',
            'body': {'body':""},
            'desciption': 'create a record in database'
        },
          {
            'Endpoint': '/recrodss/id/update',
            'method': 'PUT',
            'body':  {'body':""},
            'desciption': 'return one single record'
        },

        {
            'Endpoint': '/recrodss/id/delete',
            'method': 'DELETE',
            'body': None,
            'desciption': 'Deletes and Exiting note'
        },
        
    ]

   

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRecords(request):
    records = Records.objects.all()
    serializer = RecordsSerializer(records, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['GET'])
def getRecord(request,pk):
    record = Records.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = RecordsSerializer(record, many=False)
    return Response(serializer.data)


@api_view(['POST'])
def createRecord(request):
    data = request.data
    record = Records
    
    Records.objects.create(
        tempratures = data['tempratures'],
        location = data['location'],
        land_area = data['land_area']
    )
    serializer = RecordsSerializer(record, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['PUT'])
def updateRecord(request,pk):
    data = request.data
    record = Records.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = RecordsSerializer(record, data=request.PUT)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['DELETE'])
def deleteRecord(request,pk):
    record = Records.objects.get(id=pk)
    record.delete()
    return Response("Record has been deleted")
```

**serilizer.py**

```
from django.db.models import fields
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer, Serializer

from .models import Records


class RecordsSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Records
        fields = ['id', 'tempratures', 'location', 'land_area']
```

**in settings.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [
    '10.0.2.2',
    'localhost',
]
```

Comment: doesn't `_retrieveRecord()` cause any exception?

Comment: It shows no error ,but dont display record on screen

Comment: it shows this E/flutter (22495): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: SocketException: OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110, address = 192.168.100.108, port = 42070

Comment: I suggest you to open chrome on your emulator and try to connect to your API from there, that would be a faster way to find the problem, +  change `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'**]`